# How do I remove the Visual Basic Project types?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm never going to create a Visual Basic Project. Can I remove these from my IDE? Too many times I've created a new project not realizing I've been defaulted to the Visual Basic Projects and mistakenly create a Visual Basic Project instead of the C# project I meant to create.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to "Programs and Features" (Vista) or "Add or Remove Programs" (XP) and select Visual Studio. Click on "Uninstall or Change" (or the equivalent).

Then select "Add or Remove features" and under "Language Tools" remove "Visual Basic".

There may be other ways of messing with the templates directly, but that feels like the most appropriate way of saying you're not interested in VB.

EDIT: (Based on comments)

You can also change the default language, either by resetting all settings or by [editing the vssettings file](http://strivinglife.com/words/post/How-to-change-your-default-language-in-Visual-Studio-2008-the-right-way.aspx).

Comment: When you first start the IDE it asks you what's going to be your default. Can't find where this setting resides...

Comment: @GSerg I was trying to find that too, let me know if you find that.

Comment: Seems like there are two ways: reset all settings or do this: http://strivinglife.com/words/post/How-to-change-your-default-language-in-Visual-Studio-2008-the-right-way.aspx

Comment: Yeah, no telling whether I will need to maintain a VB app, I don't want to uninstall VB entirely

Comment: Want to make GSerg's comment the answer

Comment: Doesn't work for Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2017 anymore

Answer (score 2):

Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs -> Look for Visual Studio version you are working on and select 'Change/Remove' ->  Remove Visual Basic from the features

Answer (score 0):

The templates are installed to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\VB.

You could try deleting that folder.  There's also a cache folder in the IDE directory.

If that doesn't work or something screws up, you can always reinstall them by running a visual studio command prompt and typing "devenv /installvstemplates".